# Unique int to int hash

Tags: hash

I'm curious as to whether or not there's some simple and/or well known hash method with the following properties:

1. It transforms a 32-bit int into another 32-bit int
2. No two non-equal inputs produce the same output
3. It shouldn't be immediately obvious from looking at the output that two inputs were similar (in terms of difference and bitmask), meaning that hash(a) and hash(a+1) should have vastly different outputs, as should hash(a) and hash(a & 0x100000). (This rules out simply XORing with a random value.)

While such systems must obviously exist in theory, are there any in practice?

Comment: Sounds more like encryption rather than hashing, especially because of (2).

Comment: True, sounds like a 32-bit block cipher is what you want.

Comment: Yep, I would hesitate to call any bijective function a hash. What you're asking for is a 32-bit block cipher, perhaps Skip32.

Comment: Regarding whether or not it constitutes a hash, I make no requirement about the process being easily reversible. As such, the requirements could indeed, but also not exclusively, be solved by ciphers.

Comment: Your problem makes me think of [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) or, the more secure, [Triple DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES). 32-bit rather than 64-bit input and output might be a problem, though it might not be too difficult to derive a similar process for 32-bit.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but this [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/33761/8343) on IT security could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make a bit order change array. Some encryption functions are based on this method.

```
uint8_t arr[32]={4,7,24,9,15,3,...}; // an order you know
uint32_t orgVal;
uint32_t modVal =0;
uint32_t pos = 1;

for (int i=0; i<32;i++) {
  modVal += (orgVal&pos)? (1>>arr[i]):0;
  pos*=2;
}
```

(the code was made from scratch and without IDE or testing; it may not work)

As pointed in the comments, the difference will be minimal if you look at the bits: the amount of 0s and 1s will be the same. To solve this problem you may consider using **both bit order change and xor**. Then the difference between the original and resulting values will be more significant.

Comment: `hash(2)` and `hash(3)` will still differ in only 1 bit, which might be "obvious" depending on how you look at the resulting values.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Technically, two bits would be different. hash(2) and hash(3) would have been a better example.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Aaaand I got what you meant. Yeah, you're right.

Comment: @Smallhacker: true, fixed my comment.

Answer (score 6):

There are many in practice!

A trivial solution would be to multiply the input by any odd number, and taking the bottom 32 bits of the result.  That is:

```
y = (x * YOUR_ODD_NUMBER) & 0xffffffff;
```

This does have some weaknesses, though.  It always maps zero to zero, if you choose a small number like 3 then the mapping will be fairly obvious (similarly, if you choose a large number like 0xffffffff you'll get another obvious mapping), and the least significant bit is not changed.  Generally the low bits can affect higher bits, but the high bits cannot affect lower bits.

Another approach is to exclusive-or the number with a shifted version of itself several times:

```
x ^= x >> YOUR_FIRST_SHIFT;
x ^= x << YOUR_SECOND_SHIFT;
y = x ^ (x >> YOUR_THIRD_SHIFT);
```

You can stack up as many of these trivial operations as you like to try to hide the weaknesses of individual stages.  Even if one operation on its own isn't very good, it can contribute usefully in a more complex chain of operations.  For example, exclusive-or with some constant would avoid the problem of mapping zero to zero by multiplication alone, and the shift and exclusive-or technique allows the low bits to be affected by the high bits.

If you look at [PRNGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPseudorandom_number_generators), you'll find a lot of them have a period nearly the same size as their state.  They achieve this by permuting their state in the way you have specified -- through a 1:1 mapping where the relationship between one state and the next isn't too obvious -- then they present some of that state (or all of it) as a pseudo-random number.  Some PRNGs and hashes also finish with a tempering stage, where they perform another one of these mappings to hide some of their own weaknesses.

If you run your hash function in a loop, feeding y back into x on each iteration, then you have a PRNG, and you can test the randomness of it with tools like [dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php).

Not all PRNGs have the ideally-long-period property, and that property is not necessary for a good hash function, but some PRNG algorithms can be a useful source of ideas for operations to perform and they come with comprehensive analysis.

Comment: Since I've just posted a link to this for a more specific application, I should add that I've got good distribution properties from mixing multiplies with a standard bit-reversal transform (exchange bits 31 and 0, exchange bits 30 and 1, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Try to reverse the binary representation of the number:

```
17(10) = 1110(2) -> 10111(reversed, set first bit as indicator) = 23
18(10) = 10010(2) -> 101001 = 41
```

or interchange first half of bits with second half:

```
17(10) = 11|10(2) -> 1011 = 11
18(10) = 100|10(2) -> 10100 = 20
```

I do not know for sure, but it seems should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple enough, but may not be very efficient:

- Randomly permute all 32 bit integers.
- Save the (rather large) table.

Now you can apply it two ways, and only those with the table can know what the number should be.

Comment: Just for reference (assuming my calculations are correct) you'll need 2^32 entries in this table, each being 4 bytes, thus 2^34 = 17179869184 bytes = 16 TB storage space required.

Comment: And it also might be quite a bit of effort to shuffle 16 TBs of data.

Comment: @Dukeling It is definately not something to do on the fly, but with good hardware the creation should (just) be managable. And the use of the table should be fairly quick.

Comment: @Dukeling, I think you mean 16GB.

Comment: @sh1 Whoops, yeah, seems you're right. Not un-viable, but still a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach: `hash(x) = rotate-shl(x, K1) xor C`

You can combine several simple operations to achieve more "random" result, like `rotate-shl/shr`, `bit-reverse`, `xor`, `not` and so on.